# Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?

Imagine situation when you can access a weak Wi-Fi signal from a free hotspot (coffee shop) signal near window, but want to work in the middle of the room. Then we can put the phone on the window sill to spread the signal over the entire home.

Is it feasible?

Comment: [How to use Android in Wi-Fi repeater mode by bridging Wi-Fi with Access Point?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202336/218526).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is yes, there is an open-source project available that does exactly that.

To quote:

> It is a software designed to help you by-pass Great Firewall of China
>   (GFW). Different from similar softwares, it is designed to run as
>   router instead of running as a client installed on some device. Being
>   router means, you can have one thing (Android mobile phone, for
>   example) running fqrotuer, then other devices can just connect the
>   wireless network created by fqrouter.

Blog: [fqrouter](http://fqrouter.tumblr.com/post/47612325480/android-mobile-as-wifi-repeater)
Source: [fqrouter](http://fqrouter.com/)

Comment: From the linked page: "Wifi repeater is a unique feature, however it requires hardware/driver support", so the answer is, "It depends on your device." Also, that feature requires Android 4.

Comment: Early 2016 update: the app requires root, and does only work on some devices.  The worst news is that it currently seems broken - as it's main function is to be a VPN - and the servers have been shut down - so it does not start up.  I managed to extract the Python wifi.py code from the project and kind of get it working - on a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4 and a couple LG Android 4.4 devices I have.  But it requires python and other binaries that do not work on Android 5.0 due to PIE requirements.   If anyone else is trying to revive it, post here :)

Comment: @RoundSparrow hilltx do you still have the modded apk hanging around? I'd like to try it on my rooted LG G2 KK

Answer (score 11):

No. To do this would broadly speaking require multiple Wifi interfaces (or specialized software) which is not readily available (or easily installable) on Android.

In general this is done on Linux using something like hostapd in master mode: I don't believe that is easily setup on any Android phone.

Comment: Just found one solution that I can end up with: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1065652 but it assumes usb cable connecction between the lapton and the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I wrote [VPN Hotspot](https://github.com/Mygod/VPNHotspot) that is able to do this if you have a rooted Android 5.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, there is an application that I tested with this functionality

[NetShare tethering (no root) application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&hl=en) is  a solution to the problem addresed.

> Now this application uses a vpn proxy to route traffic from device
>   connected to Wi-Fi network to another client via a p2p connectivity.

Thus allowing to "share wi-fi over wifi" or act as a repeater
 through **Wi-Fi direct**

- Essentially, it uses a HTTP proxy to route traffic to the client and configuring the connection is fairly easy:

  1. Go to connection settings of any device e.g PC, Iphone etc (but in this case used a Symbian device)
  2. Add the wireless access point if not done already, and input the Wi-Fi direct Group password.
  3. Under advanced settings change proxy settings:

  `Server: 192.168.49.1`

  `Port: 8282`

  (remember to allow this port on firewall settings for other devices)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of Android 10, there is an option called “Enable Wi-Fi Coverage Extend Feature" in Developer Settings to turn on the WiFi extender/repeater feature.

[image: Screenshot of Developer Console from Android 10]

Comment: Looks like this option is not a standard Android feature and is only available on some manufacturers. Preliminary research shows that OnePlus, Xiaomi, and Nokia has this, but not AOSP (ref: [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/coverage-extend-feature.3844013/))

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Alcatel One Touch Glory 2s has this function. You can choose to tether wi-fi via wi-fi or mobile data. You can create the SSID and password too. I used this phone as repeater to my home wifi router.