# Can I use an existing Wifi Network as source for internet connectivity and still enable WiFi tethering?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/can-we-use-an-android-phone-as-a-wi-fi-repeater)

It is possible to use android as WiFi access point using 3G - but, **is there a way to use an existing wifi connection and not 3g as the source?**

Here where I am there is a wifi connection but it works only with openvpn, so I can use it with a laptop or rooted Android but I also have an iPad which can't use openvpn, so I thought I will use my android device as a private access point for my iPad. Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do the same thing as this previous question abouit using an Android device as a wifi repeater http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/can-we-use-an-android-phone-as-a-wi-fi-repeater