# Android phone as hotspot and using wireless connection

Tags: wi-fi, dhcp

Is it possible to make an Android phone a hotspot and make it use wireless connection?

Is there any programmatical control over DHCP?

Comment: You mean like this? [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12616)

Comment: @Dino Velić If the question has an answer that works for you, just upvote the answer in that question. Then, we will flag this question as a duplicate. Let us know if that answer helped you.

Comment: @geffchang Dino needs a little more rep to be able to upvote unfortunately...