# Can I share my wifi connection to wifi tethering?

Tags: wi-fi, tethering

Can I do it on my android? I seem can't find any reference for it.

Comment: As in [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12616)

Answer (score 0):

Tethering is a feature that is usually offered by the carrier for an additional fee.  You should check with your carrier.  Also it would have helped to include which android device you have.....