# How to share Android "Reverse-tethered" internet via Android WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, internet, tethering

Before going into main question, we do know that :

- we can do Reverse Tethering from PC into android (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371345)
- And we can share current phone internet connection via Portable WiFi hotspot (or similar apps in Google Play)

Now the question is :

"Is there a way to share the reverse-tethered internet (as we known connected via `usb0` interface) via "Android WiFi Hotspot?"

To make it easier, here's the schema:

[image: schema]
<sup>Schema of my setup (click image for larger variant)</sup>

*Additional Notes :

- Actually I don't give a limit which version of the Android (so if it's just compatible in higher version e.g. 4.2, it's okay for me), but I prefer it works on 2.3.x (Gingerbread)
- Some explanations of how to make APN (Infrastructure Mode) on Android (just like Wireless Router/[`netsh wlan hostednetwork`] on Windows 7/8) might be really helpful too.
- And also some explanations about how to masquerade (internet sharing) between two interfaces in Android. (such as ICS in Windows or Masquerade/iptables thingy in Linux-based)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Comment: @t0mm13b No. The OP doesn't want to know how to *set up* reverse tether, but how to *share* that connection to other devices.

Comment: yeah, that's quite different that just reverse tether.. it's more advanced which, after you tether, you do "masquerade" sharing from usb0 into wlan0 and broadcast that as wifi hotspot. i understand that mistake that pretty "similar". please let LO this one. thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw: You might wish to take a look at [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12616/16575) and see how it applies to your case. Don't forget to let us know here then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to make it work.  Here is an "OSI-like" diagram of my setup, if it makes sense:

```
 ____________________   ______________________________    ____________
|   LinuxVM <----+  |  |                              |  |            |
|  VirtualBox    |  |  |                              |  |            |
| Windows7(host) |  |  | +--> AndroidPhone <-------+  |  | +-->Laptop |
|  (USB)         +-------+   (USB)  (wifi-HotSpot) +-------+   (wifi) |
|___________________|  |______________________________|  |____________|
```

The script is located at the XDA forum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=50236807&postcount=9

```
## 0.a. Connect android-phone to PC through USB.
## 0.b Enable Settings|...|Tethering 
##  (so that the device gets detected by the PC's kernel, you should see the following with 'dmsg':
##         [    3.976599] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:0b.0-1, RNDIS device, 4e:d5:8c:7b:4f:5a
## Enable Settings|...|Wifi-Hotspot


## Setup usb reverse-tethering.
#  from: http://forum.xda-developers.com/show....php?t=2287494
#
#  Yours device might be 'rndis0' or something else.  Check by just typing 'netcfg'.
#
netcfg usb0 dhcp
busybox route add default gw 10.42.0.1 dev usb0


## Disable mobile-data.
#
busybox ifconfig rmnet_usb0  0.0.0.0


## Masquerade through USB.
#
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o usb0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT


## Set DNS (if neccessary, ie google's 8.8.4.4).
#
setprop net.dns1 XX.YY.ZZ.WW
```

Comment: man.. the wait is over. this is the godlike answer XD Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Excuse me, would you please tell me where to write and execute this script to allow wifi tethering while reverse tethering from usb? And please, is it a one way process or is it temporal?

Comment: 1. it's temporal. it breaks if any of interface down (offline) or restarted.
2. write this script via text editor and save it as <filename>.sh, execute it via terminal (emulator).

Comment: I able to access PC internet in android mobile using "AndroidTool.exe" tool now can anyone tell me what is next step to share the internet using wifi-HotSpot to other devices. above command tried still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tool special for that use case: [tetherspot](https://github.com/cuamckuu/tetherspot)

This script simplifies reverse USB tethering with WiFi hotspot on **non-rooted** Android devices

The main idea is to use

- Gnirehtet on PC to start reverse USB tethering via VPN and `adb`
- Proxy server on Android to route WiFi hotspot traffic to VPN