# Using Android to PC over Wifi apps while device is hotspot

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

Is there a way for me to configure my wifi hotspot so that I can use apps such as IP webcam while the hotspot is the PC's only internet connection?

Comment: Please take a look at [Can we use an Android phone as a Wi-Fi repeater?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12616/16575) :)

Comment: Not a dupe! See my answer

Comment: @Izzy: ipwebcam runs **on** the phone and acts as a network camera, it opens a tcp port on the wifi interface only, which is inaccessible in the hotspot mode

Comment: Sorry for that – it was not clear from the question. I understood it was about some IPCam in the local network the OP wanted to monitor, and thus needed to access the local WLAN *from the Android device*. @Jacxel: you might want to [edit] your question for clarification ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an intermediate wifi AP to which both android and your laptop connect. The integrated wifi hotspot functionality won't work as it does *only* forward the internet connection and hides the rest (it adds a new 192.168.42/24 subnet and does NAT internally).

Technically speaking, of course, there's a way to do it. But it requires root and you would need to setup the network by hand (iptables, ip tools required) *and* make sure that the app does bind to the wifi hotspot standard gateway IP 192.168.42.129 and that there are no firewall rules to block it.

Comment: So there is no easy fix to this problem?