# Turn On Both Wifi and Wifi Hotspot

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, settings, wifi-hotspot

Currently I am using HTC Desire A8181. Currently it is connected to some wifi for Internet. I need to use this device as a Wifi Hotspot to connect Multiple devices. Need Some one help to use Both Wifi and Wifi hotspot.

Comment: See: [Android as WiFi bridge with AP](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37141/16575) / [Can I use the HTC Desire HD Wifi Hotspot feature to share a wireless network instead of mobi…](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/7504/16575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device would need to have two separate radios to be able to do this.

- Radio one for the wifi client
- Radio two for the wifi accesspoint

As phones cannot be upgraded with additional wifi cards, this is not possible.

(Technically it would be possible if the device had a USB-OTG capable USB port, but yours doesn't have this, and secondly the standard firmwares don't support such a setup either)